# Tikz: How can I use the power of LaTeX to find the rotation angle of the ellipse?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I need to rotate my second ellipse around some angle.  I have made guesses and determined it is around `88.5` degrees.  However, I want to identify the exact angle.

The code I have so far is:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.6789}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{1.524}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltanu}{107}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\am}{1.1442}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{88.5}
    \draw[dashed] (-2 * \c, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \begin{scope}[rotate around = {\angle:(0, 0)}]
      \draw[dashed] (2 * \ctilde, 0) -- (0, 0);
    \end{scope}
    \node[scale = .75, fill = orange, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F)
    at (0, 0) {};
    \node[scale = .75, fill = white, big dot = {below: \(F^*\)}] (FS)
    at (-2 * \c cm, 0) {};
    \draw[red, thick, name path = r2] (0, 0) circle (1.523679cm);
    \draw[blue, thick, name path = r1] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
    \draw[name path = ecc2768] (-\c, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
    \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r1}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
    coordinate (P1) node[fill, big dot = {right: \(P_1\)}, minimum size = 3pt]
    {};
    \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r2}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
    coordinate (P2) node[fill, big dot = {left: \(P_2\)}, minimum size = 3pt]
    {};
    \draw (P1) -- (P2) node[scale = .75, fill = white, shape = circle, pos = .5]
    {\(c\)};
    \draw let
      \p0 = (F),
      \p1 = (P1),
      \p2 = (P2),
      \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
      \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
      \n3 = {.35cm}
    in (F) +(\n1:\n3) arc [radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
    node[scale = .45, pos = 0.5, above = 10pt] {\pgfmathparse{\n2 - \n1}%            
      $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$
    };
    \begin{scope}[rotate around = {\angle:(0, 0)}]
      \draw (\ctilde, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \btilde cm);
      \node[scale = .75, fill = white, big dot = {above: \(\tilde{F}^*\)}] (FST)
      at (2 * \ctilde cm, 0) {};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

From the picture, we can see that guess seems decent but it may or may not be correct.

Is there a some built in function that will let us rotate the near side of the ellipse to the the intersection point P2 and the far side to P1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by finding the intersection `P3` between the unrotated ellipse and the circle with radius `r1`, and then calculating the angle `P1-F-P3`: That's the angle you need to rotate the ellipse by:

[image]

```
  \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2.5pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 5pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{0.2768}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\etilde}{0.6789}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rone}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{1.524}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltanu}{107}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.36}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\am}{1.1442}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a * sqrt(1 - \e^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\btilde}{\a * sqrt(1 - (\etilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctilde}{sqrt(\a^2 - (\btilde)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{88.5}
    \node[scale = .75, fill = orange, big dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F)
    at (0, 0) {};
    \draw[draw=none, thick, name path = r2] (0, 0) circle (1.523679cm);
    \draw[blue, thick, name path = r1] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
    \draw[name path = ecc2768] (-\c, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
    \draw[name intersections = {of = ecc2768 and r1}] (F) -- (intersection-1)
    coordinate (P1) node[fill, big dot = {right: \(P_1\)}, minimum size = 3pt]
    {};
    \draw [name path = ecc6789unrotated, gray!50, thick] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \btilde cm);
      \draw [name intersections={of=r1 and ecc6789unrotated}]
      (intersection-2) circle [radius=1.5pt] node [above] {$P_3$}
      let
        \p0=(F),
        \p1=(P1),
        \p2=(intersection-2),
        \n1={atan2(\x1-\x0,\y1-\y0)},
        \n2={atan2(\x2-\x0,\y2-\y0)},
        \n3={\n1-\n2}
      in
      \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}}
        [rotate=\n3] (\ctilde, 0) ellipse (\a cm and \btilde cm);

      \node at (0,3) {The angle of rotation is: \pgfmathparse{\myangle} $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^\circ$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: You are great at this.  I wish I was able to do this on my own like you.  How can I use `\n3` out of the let statement?  Would name global path work?

Comment: @dustin: Usually `\n3` is only available in the `path` command with the `let` statement. However, you can store the result in a macro by putting something like `\pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}}` in the path (so `\draw ... let ... \n3={\n1-\n2} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myangle{\n3}} [rotate=\n3] ...`)

Comment: That didn't work.  Can we print out `\n3` some how so I can record it?

Comment: @dustin: I've edited my answer to show how to save the result.

Comment: Thanks.  My angle of 88.5 was pretty close to the actual value of 88.23.